# When pasteing value into input area, can't capture value

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a button and an input area. When the input's length is filled (14) - then the button's class will be active. That currently works, however, when the user pastes a value into the input area, the length is zero until the user enters something else. My goal is to display the active class on the button when the paste is done if the length of the value is 14.

JS

```
 $('#number', '#form')
   .keydown(function (e) {
    var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
    $phone = $(this);
    $len = $phone.val().length;
    console.log($len);
    // Auto-format
    if (key !== 8 && key !== 9) {
        if ($phone.val().length === 13){
            $('#form div a:eq(0)').removeClass('inactive');
        }
        if (($phone.val().length === 14) && (key == 13)){
            e.preventDefault(); 
            $('#form div a:eq(0)').trigger('click');
        }
        if ($phone.val().length < 13){
            $('#form div a:eq(0)').addClass('inactive');
        }
    }
    if (key == 8){
        $('#form div a:eq(0)').addClass('inactive');
    }

    // Allow numeric, tab, backspace, delete, and arrow keys only
    return (
        key == 8 || 
        key == 9 ||
        key == 46 ||
        key == 86 || //copy+paste
        key == 67 ||
        key == 17 ||
        key == 91 || // end  
        (key >= 37 && key <= 40)||
        (key >= 48 && key <= 57) ||
        (key >= 96 && key <= 105)
    ); 
});

 document.getElementById('number').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
 var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3]   : '');
 });
```

HTML

```
      <form id="form">
            <input id="number" type="text" maxlength="14" placeholder='(100) 100-1000'>
            <div>
                <a class='bt inactive'>Enter</a>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Why do you have the event bound to the form itself, and where are you returning?

Comment: Anyway -> https://jsfiddle.net/odhs7uvz/

Comment: @adeneo why wouldn't you submit that as an answer?

Comment: @CarlMarkham - it doesn't really do all the things the OP seems to want, it's just my opinion that the code in that fiddle is enough. Actually, thinking about it, it's too much, the OP should use a button, not an anchor, to submit the form, and just drop that code as well.

Comment: @adeneo Fair enough, it was my understanding that we should provide an answer to the particular query, not try and improve the OP's code. There are many ways code can be changed for the better. BTW, I'm not disagreeing with your methods, just trying to understand better.

Comment: @CarlMarkham - I think it's okay to improve the OP's code, as long as your answer doesn't completely change the premise of the question, and sometimes you have the infamous [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) etc. where you try to read between the lines. I also thing answering in comments should be avoided, but sometimes when you ask something and don't get a response, I at least tend to just post a solution I think might work in the comments, that I don't think would be an answer that fit very well otherwise. Then again, I don't follow Meta ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `input` event. This event is triggered when eve the input changes. `keyup` and `keydown` will fire even if the input hasn't changed. Pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> will trigger `keydown` even if nothing has changed. `input` will only be triggered if it has changed, ie: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> (paste)

```js
$('#number', '#form')
   .on('input', function (e) {
    var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
    $phone = $(this);
    $len = $phone.val().length;
    console.log($len);
    // Auto-format
    if (key !== 8 && key !== 9) {
        if ($phone.val().length === 13){
            $('#form div a:eq(0)').removeClass('inactive');
        }
        if (($phone.val().length === 14) && (key == 13)){
            e.preventDefault(); 
            $('#form div a:eq(0)').trigger('click');
        }
        if ($phone.val().length < 13){
            $('#form div a:eq(0)').addClass('inactive');
        }
    }
    if (key == 8){
        $('#form div a:eq(0)').addClass('inactive');
    }

    // Allow numeric, tab, backspace, delete, and arrow keys only
    return (
        key == 8 || 
        key == 9 ||
        key == 46 ||
        key == 86 || //copy+paste
        key == 67 ||
        key == 17 ||
        key == 91 || // end  
        (key >= 37 && key <= 40)||
        (key >= 48 && key <= 57) ||
        (key >= 96 && key <= 105)
    ); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
            <input id="number" type="text" maxlength="14" placeholder='(100) 100-1000'>
            <div>
                <a class='bt inactive'>Enter</a>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also use another event `input` so it triggers your function on keydown and on input as well. Check out this working example using your code

```
$('#number', '#form').on('keydown input',function(){});
```

```js
$('#number', '#form')
   .on('keydown input', function (e) {
    var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
    $phone = $(this);
    $len = $phone.val().length;
    console.log($len);
    // Auto-format
    if (key !== 8 && key !== 9) {
        if ($phone.val().length === 13){
            $('#form div a:eq(0)').removeClass('inactive');
        }
        if (($phone.val().length === 14) && (key == 13)){
            e.preventDefault(); 
            $('#form div a:eq(0)').trigger('click');
        }
        if ($phone.val().length < 13){
            $('#form div a:eq(0)').addClass('inactive');
        }
    }
    if (key == 8){
        $('#form div a:eq(0)').addClass('inactive');
    }

    // Allow numeric, tab, backspace, delete, and arrow keys only
    return (
        key == 8 || 
        key == 9 ||
        key == 46 ||
        key == 86 || //copy+paste
        key == 67 ||
        key == 17 ||
        key == 91 || // end  
        (key >= 37 && key <= 40)||
        (key >= 48 && key <= 57) ||
        (key >= 96 && key <= 105)
    ); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
     <input id="number" type="text" maxlength="14" placeholder='(100) 100-1000'><br /><br />
     <div>
        <a class='bt inactive'>Enter</a>
     </div>
</form>
```